# Ruby: How can I capture all characters, ignoring whitespace?

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to capture all word characters, ignoring whitespace in a given string.

```
str = "Hello there how are you?"
```

I want the result to be:

```
"Hellotherehowareyou"
```

I have tried:

```
str[/(\w*)*/]
# => "Hello"
```

…but it returns the first word only. How do I capture all the word characters?

Comment: Can you explain the intention? `str.gsub(/[^\w]/,'')` would do this for you if numbers and underscores are okay otherwise `str.gsub(/[^a-z]/i,'')`

Comment: Try `str.gsub(/\s/, '')`.

Comment: `str.gsub(/\W/, '')` would work, i.e. removing the non-word characters.

Comment: Hey, @engineersmnky, how ya doin? Can `[^\w]` be simplified? (Ah, Stefan just posted a spoiler.) The OP says, "ignoring whitespace", not "ignoring everything but word characters".

Comment: @CarySwoveland We could go with `/[^[:alpha:]]/` in place of `/[^a-z]/i` which would be simpler I guess since it avoids the case insensitive flag. *"I want to capture all word characters"* and *"I want the result to be "Hellotherehowareyou"* suggests otherwise

Comment: Not on a computer right now but `str.scan(/\w+/).join` should work as well. Who wants to benchmark?

Comment: The question is not clear. Is it known that the string contains only word characters and whitespace? If so, `str.gsub(/\s/, '')`. If not, you need to say what is to be done with the characters that are neither word characters nor whitespace. @Stefan is being coy. He wants to do the benchmark himself.

Comment: To extract all word characters, you may use `s.scan(/\w/)`, but here, it looks as if `s.gsub(/\W+/, '')` is the answer (judging by the expected output)

Comment: @Stefan [Benchmarks](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/FondWholeCamel) left out the ones where the results differ (from `fruity`)  but they track the same. No spaces (`str.gsub(/\s/, '')`) is much faster but I am not sure it meets the criteria

Comment: @CarySwoveland @Stefan `s.tr('^a-zA-Z0-9_','')` is way faster (~ 30x ± 10.0)

Comment: @engineersmnky, how were you able to include two user names in one comment? I thought the limit was one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just typed it (no idea if the notification works). In the past I would post the comment then edit and add another name which worked (again no idea about notification)

Answer (score 1):

### What's Wrong

`str[/(\w*)*/]` returns a substring, rather than scanning the whole string for matches or removing undesirable characters. You'd be better off using one of the other String methods like #gsub, #tr, #delete, #scan, or #match, depending on what your real intent is.

### Use Character Properties or Classes

If you're looking for a *robust* solution, [Ruby character properties](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) or [POSIX character classes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) are probably the way to go. To get the results you provided in your original post, you could use the Unicode-aware `\p{Alpha}` property. For example:

```
str.scan(/\p{Alpha}/).join
#=> "Hellotherehowareyou"
```

Alternatively, if you just want to delete spaces and the question mark, and you don't care about other types of characters, then [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-delete) may suffice for your specific corpus.

```
str.delete ' ?'
#=> "Hellotherehowareyou"
```

If you need a more complex way to select or reject elements from a stream of characters, you could even do something like:

```
str.chars.select { _1 =~ /\p{Alpha}/ }.join
#=> "Hellotherehowareyou"
```

There are certainly other approaches, too. The KISS and YAGNI principles probably apply. Meanwhile, choose a solution based on readability and the semantic intent of your code, since most solutions will yield very similar results for your specific example.

Comment: The last example is not correct. `_1` is an undefined local variable instead this should be `str.chars.select { |a| a =~ /\p{Alpha}/ }.join` or `str.chars.grep(/\p{Alpha}/).join`

Comment: @engineersmnky It works fine, provided you are on a current MRI Ruby. This feature was introduced in Ruby 2.7.0, so maybe you need to upgrade.

Comment: My apologies although it is more than a bit presumptive to assume that everyone is using the leading edge ruby version (especially since 2.5.8 and 2.6.6 are both still very current). Possibly adding backwards compatible alternatives (that would have worked since 1.8.7) would be useful as well.